# How could I retrieve AWS Lambda public IP address by using Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda, ip-address

My application is to use an link(url) to invoke lambda function ,then I want to know public IP of lambda and get page source. How could I get lambda public IP by using python?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE : Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help :)

Comment: Try https://gist.github.com/kixorz/3b172e2fc3ce35421ee9. The code is simple to adapt to Python

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can curl to `checkip.amazonaws.com` to get the public IP.

```
import requests
requests.get('http://checkip.amazonaws.com').text.rstrip()
```

Output:

```
52.x.147.64
```

Answer (score 6):

```
import urllib3
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request('GET', 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com')
response.__dict__
```

IP address found in the `'_body'` attribute.

Alternative solution due to:

1. unable to use `requests` as it's not part of the core
2. botocore vendored version removed by AWS found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/)

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest:

```
from botocore.vendored import requests
requests.get('http://checkip.amazonaws.com').text.rstrip()
```

inside your `lambda` function.

Otherwise you may get an error that says that lambda cannot find `requests` unless you created your lambda from a .zip file that includes `requests` installed via `pip`

Comment: Thanks a lot.Just like you said,I created my lambda function from a .zip file containing requests installed via pip.

Comment: This solution no longer works because the vendored version of requests has been removed from botocore. https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/

Comment: it works but with DeprecationWarning:
This dependency was removed from Botocore and will be removed from Lambda after 2021-12-01.  https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/developer/removing-the-vendored-version-of-requests-from-botocore/. Install the requests package, 'import requests' directly, and use the requests.get() function instead.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `import requests`, you can use `urllib` that does not require pip.

The sample code is below;

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = 'http://checkip.amazonaws.com'
    with urlopen(Request(url)) as response:
        print(response.read().decode('utf-8'))
```